# python: can't open file 'bot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or director

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

---

```
import disnake from disnake.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", help_command=None, intents=disnake.Intents.all())
@bot.event async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot {bot.user} is ready to work!")
bot.run()
```

---

Вот код, если что апи вставленно, но я не понимаю почему когда я захожу в Cmd мне пишет
python: can't open file 'bot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or director
не понимаю что надо сделать

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать бота для дискорда

Comment: И как запускаете? Указываете путь до файла? Текущая директория совпадает с той, в которой находится файл?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно:

1. Название файла должно совпадать с тем которое запускаете, к примеру `main.py`
2. Находится в одной директории с файлом

Если всё сделано правильно напишите команду `python <название файла>`

Пример:

```sh
python main.py
```

Comment: Можете как то со мной связаться в тг или же в дискорде, чтобы я вам показал , а вы мне объяснили

Comment: Кидайте контакты сюда

Comment: Mokaki4 дискорд или же @Mokaki4 тг